# Firebase Database query equalTo

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am wanting to fetch all users that contain a child node 'notificationToken' and exclude all users that don't have this node. I am using the following:

```
const ref = admin.database().ref('/Users');
const users = await ref.orderByChild('notificationToken').equalTo(****WHAT GOES HERE****).once('value').then((snapshot) => snapshot.val());
```

I'm not sure if equalTo can do what I want, I know I can use it to match exact strings or booleans, but how can I use it to match if the user has the notificationToken node?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `equalTo` to match the exact value of a node/property in the database.

So:

```
ref.orderByChild('notificationToken').equalTo(value)
```

Returns child nodes of `ref` for which the `notificationToken` property has the exact same value as `value`. From that last link it follows that you can use `startAt(null)` to get all child nodes that have the property, no matter what its value or type.

The `value` can be any allowed JSON type, and must match the type that is stored in the database. So if `notificationToken` is a string value, `value` should be a string too.

For more on this see the Firebase documentation on [sorting and filtering data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data), and specifically the section on [how query data is ordered](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#data-order).

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I know I can match a value, but I am wanting to select the data if it has the node regardless of the value inside. I am using startAt now as I know what the value will always start with, but was hoping for a more robust way...

Comment: This is why I explicitly called out the [how data is sorted](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#data-order) documentation. You can `startAt(null)` to get all child nodes that have the property.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have tried using startAt(null) but it returns all objects not just the ones that have a notificationToken node.

Comment: Hmmm.... I thought `null` was the one. But it turns out startAt(false)` may be the right approach. See my repro here: https://jsbin.com/zowafug/3/edit?js,console

Comment: Hi thanks again. Have tried startAt(' ') & startAt(false) and neither gets the result. Just want to confirm that I need to check for the existence of 'notificationToken' not it's value. i.e {name: 'Test', notificationToken: 'sdsd' }, {name: 'Test 2'} - I want to get the object with name Test

Comment: If you check my jsbin, you'll see that I get 3 nodes back, where I actually have 4. Node `3` doesn't have the `notificationToken` property, so is not returned.